# ActionScript 3 Contact Form

Tags: forms, actionscript, contacts

How do you connect to a mysql database with AS3 to post data from my Flash application? I want to build a very basic contact form in Flash a client types in their email password to login thats it! 
In my Flash file. I have two variables email, and password to send to the php file which I have already created. I have set the mysql_query inside the php file to retrieve and send information to the database.
I've come across this error which i cant figure out whats the matter... if someone can help with a second pair of eyes i would appreciate it a lot.... This is some of my code below for my AS3 file its too long to show you it in full....
I hope this doesnt sound a stupid question but I am fairly new to ActionScript 3 after coming from Javascript. But could the cause of my problem be the textInput fields? I am unsure if they have been instantiated properly or filled out correctly. I have give the textInput fields the instance names of email and ps_wd. I am wondering when the form has been submitted if the data inside the textfields has been sent correctly. I like to hear your thoughts and opinions.
Thank You

btn_one.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnHandler);

```
  //Validate form fields
  function btnHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
    trace("Form has been submitted");

    //Check to see if the fields are empty
    function showResult(event:Event):void{
       status_Txt.text =  "" + event.target.data.systemResult;
           trace(event.target.data.systemResult);
           trace("Its been clicked");
    }

    var phpVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    var phpFileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("phpExample.file.com/");
    phpFileRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    phpFileRequest.data = phpVars;


    //Fill in the text Input fields
    //TEXT INPUT FILELDS 
    phpVars.email = email.text;
    phpVars.ps_wd = ps_wd.text;

    var phpLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    phpLoader.load(phpFileRequest);
    phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
    phpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showResult);


    email.text = "";
    ps_wd.text = ""; 


    }

   email.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyHandler);


   ps_wd.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyEnter);




  function keyHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
     if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER)
     trace("keyboard has functioned");
   }


   function keyEnter(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
       if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER)
       trace("keyboard has been pressed");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just at a glance, you're specifying the dataFormat and event listener of the URLLoader  *after* loading the data... you need to specify them before.  Also, it's best to avoid nesting functions such as you've done.

Comment: Cheers Hunter. Okay I did what you suggested by stating the dataFormat and eventListener BEFORE the URLLoader however, nothing changes unfortunately...Hoping to any other suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkEngland - if you want help on this site - you'll need to be more specific.  If you update your code and you still have problems, be sure to update the code in your question too.  If you're getting a specific error, then state that error.  If you're expecting something specific to happen and it's not happening, then state exactly what should be happening, and what's happening instead.  It's hard to help you when the problem is something vague like "it's not working".  Also, you should accept answers when they answer your question, or at least comment on the ones that don't.